# In Android how to I set a custom attribute with new Button()?

Tags: android, android-button, android-custom-attributes

I'm declaring a button using:

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setText(itemSet[i]);
btn.setId(i);
```

I need to add a custom attribute that will be used upon click.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can attach any data as a tag of the button using `setTag`.

```
String attribute = "Hello";
btn.setTag(attribute);
```

You can then get back the tag later with `getTag`.

```
String attribute = (String) btn.getTag();
```

If you need to bind multiple values to a View, declare IDs in values/tags.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="tag_first" type="id" />
    <item name="tag_second" type="id" />
</resources>
```

And use them as the first parameter of setTag.

```
btn.setTag(R.id.tag_first, "First");
btn.setTag(R.id.tag_second, "Second");
```

You can then get the bound values as follows:

```
String first = (String) btn.getTag(R.id.tag_first);
String second = (String) btn.getTag(R.id.tag_second);
```

Comment: but, what about if I need more than one tag ?

Comment: Hi, Francisco, I edited my answer and added a version for multiple values.

Comment: looks good. But why don't you declare the tag-id as static in a class ? is it better to declare them in the xml ?

Comment: Actually, these tag IDs needs to be declared in XML, or you get an error.

Answer (score 1):

A built in method that could be used is the [setTag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29) method on the button itself. You can use a tag to store any information you would like, including complex objects. This works on all views.

```
    btn.setTag(myObject);

    public void onClick(View view) {
            MyObject myObject = (MyObject)view.getTag();
    }
```